# Shouldn't have got or gotten

Tags: grammar, got-gotten

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “I have got” and “I have gotten”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten)

In this example, my teacher thinks it should be *got*, but I feel like *gotten* is better:

> I shouldn't have **got** / **gotten** married.

Which one is correct?

Comment: It depends on which dialect you speak. They're both correct. I think one is more frequent in British English and the other in American, but I can't remember which. I use both forms without noticing which.

Comment: _Gotten_ would rarely be found in British English in this context.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gotten?rq=1

Comment: @BillFranke: I'm not surprised to see you weigh in here. Aren't you somewhat of an [expert](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101655/how-closely-synonymous-are-forward-and-straightforward/101672#comment206729_101672) on this subject? ;^)

Comment: I remember being told that "have gotten" was wrong in school (Northern Irish, so what was considered the "correct" form in the textbooks would generally be closer British than American, and often were British texts). On the one hand this backs up what @BarrieEngland says, but on the other hand, if nobody was ever using it, they wouldn't have bothered telling us not to.

Comment: @Jon: there may be a difference between England and Ireland here. It's quite possible that Americans didn't invent *gotten*, but acquired it from the Irish.

Comment: @PeterShor there may, which is why I was clear I'm from somewhere else on the one hand, but that our texts where mostly British on the other. Some texts we used where Irish or specifically Northern Irish though, so I can't be sure. All that said, I think that use of *gotten* was unknown to me until I was told not to use it. Maybe it's found in some regions, but rarely, and hence taught against for being unusual in the wider context.

Comment: *Gotten* has a long history in British English. The OED’s etymological note on _get_ says ‘In England the form _gotten_ of the past participle is almost obsolete (excluding dialects) being superseded by _got_; in U.S. literature gotten is still very common, although Webster 1864 gave it as “‘obsolescent”.’ It survives in British English in _ill-gotten_.

Comment: @BarrieEngland ah, well that "excluding dialects" backs up my suspicion, that while it's unknown to us (or at least sounds rather American or historical) there are pockets where it persists.

Comment: @Jon Hanna. Apparently, 'in the north midlands and Yorkshire _getten_ is still the dialectal form.'

Comment: @BarrieEngland they're areas that are strong on retentions. They have some that I know of because they're also common here ("press" is still as common as "cupboard" here, and its often found there), and even "thou" took some time to die out there, as per D H Lawrence).

Comment: @J.R.: That's what happens to EFL teachers who indiscriminately read both British & American literature for a lifetime. Best to be honest about it. I'm not a purist. :-)

Comment: @Barrie: I think this is definitely a dup of [Difference between “I have got” and “I have gotten”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Agreed. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

NOAD has this usage note:

> *USAGE* As past participles of **get**, the words **got** and **gotten** both date back to Middle English. In North American English, **got** and **gotten** are not identical in use. **Gotten** usually implies the process of obtaining something ( : *he has **gotten** two tickets for the show*), while got implies the state of possession or ownership ( : *he hasn’t **got** any money*).

That usage note may describe a difference, but it doesn't say much about usage with the word *married*. Is marriage the process of obtaining something? Or does it imply a state of possession? (One could wryly answer that this might depend on the local culture and marriage traditions.)

I'm inclined to agree with the teacher, although it seems like the simplest solution may be to drop the *got/gotten* altogether. "Get married" seems almost like a phrasal verb; i.e.:

> We will get married next June.

is essentially the same as:

> We will marry next June.

so the speaker could just as well say:

> I never should have married.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that standard American usage is *gotten* here, but from [Ngrams,](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+gotten+married%2CI+have+got+married&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=) *got* was usually used in writing a century ago, and I believe many Americans use *got*.

Answer (score 1):

"I shouldn't have got married when I wasn't ready for it"
"I shouldn't have got married on such a wet day", etc'. These are the more common usage with that one.
'I shouldn't have gotten married' is used when the sentence ends there.

Comment: Indeed it ends there. Many thanks for clear explanation. :)

Comment: I think that needs some more explanation.  I wouldn't say just *got* in any of those examples.

Comment: amanda witt, your answer would be improved if you mentioned where in the world the word *got*, is more common. In England and the rest of the UK, *gotten* is normally only used when people say *ill-gotten* or *forgotten*. Using it in your example, would be something that speakers of American English, do.